# Will terminal programs like git work on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, git

It really bothers me that terminal programs like git don't work on Android. Will it work on UbuntuTouch?

If so:

- Will installing packages be possible? I read the system currently is pretty much read-only and you can't install packages like on a normal computer. Instead, you have to use an app store and install apps.
- Will compiling git from source be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gernerally: Yes. To install software using apt, you need to make the root file system writable by running this command: sudo mount -o remount,rw /
Then first run 'sudo apt-get update' to fetch the latest package list. Then you should be able to install git and diverse compiler tools like g++... But attention: Never run 'sudo apt-get (dist-)upgrade'! This can break your Ubuntu Touch installation. Also installing wrong or incompatible software can lead to this. And please remember: The device's space usually is pretty limited, so keep the possibility open for enough free space (run 'df -h' to have a look at this)...

Comment: Why is the root file system read-only in the first place?

Comment: It's for safety reasons. If you do a mistake, it's harder to reset the device than you would do it with a pc.